# How to store values of different types in a single Structure

Tags: c#

I have a text file in that has a list of strings (Example  `6|Chicago|Illinois|I-98;I-90`). I am trying to create two Classes. One class (`CityReader`) reads the text file and other file prints it. I declared a class(`CityItem`) with 4 variables, int population, string city, string state, `List<int>` Interstates.

In the `CityReader` class I created a `CityItem` `Object(CIObj)` and was able to read the file and delimit it and returning `CIObj`. But when I access this object from a different class I am only seeing the last line in the text file. This object is not returning all the values.

I realized though I am reading the file in each loop. I am not storing those values and hence the object is holding only the last object.

```
    CityItem Class-----

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    namespace ReadingAtxtFile
    {
        public class CityItem
        {
    public int Population { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public List<int> Interstates = new List<int>();      

         }
    }


    CityReader Class-----

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Collections;
    namespace ReadingAtxtFile
    {
        public class CityReader
        {
             public CityItem ReadCities(string FilePath)
             {
        CityItem CIObj = new CityItem();
        var AllLines = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath, Encoding.UTF8);
        try
        {
            foreach (var item1 in AllLines)
            {
                string[] EachLine = item1.Split('|');

                CIObj.Population = Convert.ToInt32(EachLine[0]);
                CIObj.City = EachLine[1];
                CIObj.State = EachLine[2];

                    string[] IStates = EachLine[3].Split(';');

                    foreach (var item2 in IStates)
                    {
                        var IStatesAfterSplit = item2.Split("-");
                      CIObj.Interstates.Add(Convert.ToInt32(IStatesAfterSplit[1]));
                    }              
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There is an issue with processing the data");
        }
        return CIObj;
        }          
        }
       }
```

Input TextFile:

```
6|Oklahoma City|Oklahoma|I-35;I-44;I-40
6|Boston|Massachusetts|I-90;I-93
8|Columbus|Ohio|I-70;I-71
```

I am trying to process the text file and print the data as I like. For example. population

```
Population,
City, State,
Interstates: I-35,I-40,I-45 (Sorted order)
```

Comment: You need to return a `List<CityItem>` not a single `CityItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ReadCities method needs to return some kind of collection of CityItem objects, not just a single CityItem object.  .Net supports various kinds of collections, but a List is probably best for this instance.

Then, after populating your CityItem object, before moving to the next iteration of the loop, add the CityItem object to your List.  Something like...

```
List<CityItem> listOfCityItems = new List<CityItem>();
foreach (var line in AllLines)
{
    CityItem ci = new CityITem();
    // Populate the properties of ci
    listOfCityItems.Add(ci);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, I was able to solve the problem. Appreciate it. I have one more question. I am trying to sort this list. Used Icomparable and was able to solve it. I want to print in in the following format.  83
 
New York, New York
Interstates: I-78, I-80, I-87, I-95

27

Chicago, Illinois
Interstates: I-55, I-57, I-88, I-90, I-94

15

Phoenix, Arizona
Interstates: I-8, I-10, I-17

Philadelphia, Pennsylvania
Interstates: I-76, I-95 . If you notice for philadelphia there's no population because it has population of 15. Whats the logic to skipping 15 for philadelphia

Comment: Update: I was able to figure out the logic. I assigned the population value at the end of the loop to a variable and comparing it to the next value in the loop.